# SQL no comma no decimal leading zeros

Tags: sql

If I have a number that is 1,234.56, I need to format with no decimal, no comma & leading zeros.  The output I'm seeking would be 000123456.

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you need the format to be exactly 9 characters with leading zeros?

Comment: `SELECT '000' + REPLACE(REPLACE('1,234.56', ',', ''), '.','')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000000' + REPLACE(REPLACE('1,234.56', '.', ''), ',', ''), 9) AS NewColumn
```

Result:

```
NewColumn
000123456
```

Comment: what about if the number has more than 6 characters?

Comment: Yes, this will work with 0 to 9 characters. Give it a try. Hence why I asked OP if they need exactly 9 characters. :) `SELECT RIGHT('000000000' + REPLACE(REPLACE('122,234.56', '.', ''), ',', ''), 9) AS NewColumn` result `012223456`

Answer (score 0):

This works in Oracle.  Use regexp_replace() first to remove commas and decimals in one step.  Then pad with zeroes to the left to a length of 9 characters.

Caveat: If the resulting number ends up being longer than 9 characters, it will truncate on the right.

```
select lpad(regexp_replace('1,234.56', '[,.]'), 9, '0')
from dual;
```

Hopefully this will translate to your version of SQL.